# Callback functions promise ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem displying infromation from an json using promise callback .I already display posts , but i can't display comments for each post . Ty .

Here is my code

JS

```
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'

$.ajax({
    url: root,
    method:'GET',
    data:{
        a:''
    }
})

  .done(function(post) {

      for(i=0 ; i<10;i++){
        document.write(JSON.stringify(post[i]))
        document.write('<br>')
        document.write('<br>')
        document.write('<br>')
      }

  })
 .done(function(comments){
    for(j=0; j<10;j++){
        $.ajax({
          url: root +'/'+ j+'/comments',
          method:'GET',
          comments:{
              b:''
          }

      })
            }

 })
```

Comment: why not just use jQuery `success` callback function?

Comment: Avoid `done` and  `success` callbacks, always use `then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use ES8 syntax with `async` `await`, then proceed as follows:

```js
async function getHTML() {
    const root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    const response = await $.get(root);
    let html = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        html += JSON.stringify(response[i]) + "</br>";
        comments = await $.get(root +'/' + i +'/comments');
        for (const comment of comments) {
            html += JSON.stringify(comment) + "</br>";
        }
    }
    return html;
}

getHTML().then(html => console.log(html), err => console.error(err));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is how you would do it with ES6 `Promise.all`:

```js
function getHTML() {
    var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    return $.get(root).then(function (response) {
        var html = "";
        var promises = []; // collect the requests for all comments
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            promises.push($.get(root +'/' + i +'/comments').promise());
        }
        return Promise.all(promises).then(function (response2) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                html += JSON.stringify(response[i]) + "</br>";
                for (var j = 0; j < response2.length; j++) {
                    html += JSON.stringify(response2[j]) + "</br>";
                }
            }
            return html;
        });
    });
}

getHTML().then((html) => console.log(html));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is working , but i need to use a similiar syntax of mine . i can't use your code .. It's a little advance that what i'm learning right now ..

Comment: Added an alternative that does not use `async` or `await, but  `then` and `Promise.all` (ES6).

Comment: This is what i need . Ty .

Answer (score 0):

You have asked your question twice, in two different threads for some reason. I have answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53802464/promise-callback/53802997#53802997).